# Bean method on rowEdit event of p:dataTable is not invoked

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, datatable, roweditor

I am trying edit row from `<p:dataTable>` n call bean method but the problem is bean method is not invoked on `rowEdit` event. It will be appreciable, if someone could give me the solution.

Also, my bean is already in View Scope, even not working in session scope... I have tried for all three scopes.

My codes are given below :

```
<h:form id="commentList">
    <p:dataTable id="commentTable" editable="true" paginator="true" rows="10" var="comment" value="#{commentAction.list(uID)}" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover commentTable" widgetVar="commentListTable">
        <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{commentAction.updateCommentStatus}"/>
        <p:column filterBy="#{comment.commentId}" footerText="" headerText="Comment Id" filterMatchMode="contains" sortBy="#{comment.commentId}">
            <h:outputText value="#{comment.commentId}" id="commentId"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column filterBy="#{comment.selectedText}" headerText="Selected Text" sortBy="#{comment.selectedText}">
            <h:outputText value="#{comment.selectedText}" id="selectedText"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column filterBy="#{comment.commentText}" headerText="Comment" sortBy="#{comment.commentText}">
            <h:outputText value="#{comment.commentText}" id="commentText" escape="false"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column filterBy="" headerText="Comment From" sortBy="">
            <h:outputText value="" id="commentFrom"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column filterBy="#{comment.insertedOn}" headerText="Date/Time" sortBy="#{comment.insertedOn}">
            <h:outputText value="#{comment.insertedOn}" id="insertedOn"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column filterBy="#{comment.commentStatus}" headerText="Comment Status" sortBy="#{comment.commentStatus}">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{comment.commentStatus}" id="commSatus"/>
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{commentAciton.commentStatus}" id="commentStatus" class="commentSelectBox">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="UpdateStatus" itemDisabled="true"/>
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="Open" itemLabel="Open"/>
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="Close" itemLabel="Close"/>
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="Cancel" itemLabel="Cancel"/>
                    </h:selectOneMenu>
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>
        <p:column style="width:32px">
            <p:rowEditor />
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

And bean method is:

```
public void updateCommentStatus(RowEditEvent event) {
    try {
        logger.info("comment Iddddddddddd: " + commentId);
        logger.info("comment Statusssssss: " + this.commentStatus);
        Comment comment = (Comment) event.getObject();
        logger.info("new value: " + comment.getCommentStatus());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.info("Exception caught in updateCommentStatus in CommentAction ..." + ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: The XHTML code cannot be parsed. The tag `<p:dataTable>` is untidy and missing a `>` at the end. Is this your real code? Unrelated but `listener` of `<p:ajax>` in this case, will not navigate to the stated navigation case outcome `success`. It basically expects a `void` method in the associated backing bean. Unlike `action`, the return type will simply be ignored.

Comment: @Tiny : > tag for <p:dataTable> was writing mistake... Also removing return tag from bean method, function is still not invoked... edited the bean method above...
but now i am getting exception:

Comment: com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl handlePartialResponseError
SEVERE: javax.faces.model.NoRowAvailableException

Can some one plz help

Comment: What is the scope of the bean? (In this case, It should be view scoped - `@ViewScoped` or even broader, if needed).

Comment: Yes, it is view scope only

Comment: Here in the `value` attribute (of `<p:dataTable>`) - `value="#{commentAction.list(uID)}"`, what is the argument `uID` supposed to be? Are you sure about the list which is supposed to be populated in the backing bean properly at the right place and right time (inside a method decorated/annotated by `@PostConstruct` or one of the overloaded lazy data model's `load()` methods, if you happened to use it in your real code etc)?

Comment: @tiny : no i am not using postConstruct. Plz explain its usage & importance.
And uID is urs id, comment list is retrived from db for particular uid

Comment: That's another separate question. :) [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html) is the Java docs, however. In this case, how do you populate the list which is bound to the given `<p:dataTable>` - in a getter method? If it is the case then, it has to be avoided. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2090062/1391249) is why.

Comment: Thanx a lot @tiny its working now, problem was populating the list using getter method.
But by writing code of getting list in init() resolves the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanx to @tiny problem is resolved by replacing list retrieving code from getter method to init() in postConstruct annotation.
Below is the corrected code

```
<p:dataTable id="commentTable" editable="true" paginator="true" rows="10" var="comment" value="#{commentAction.commentList}" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover commentTable" widgetVar="commentListTable">
<p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{commentAction.updateCommentStatus}"/>
  ....
  ....
  ....
</p:dataTable>
```

```java
@PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        logger.info("urs: "+ursId);
        CommentManager commentManager = new CommentManager();
        try {
            commentList = commentManager.list(1); //hardcoding ryt now
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.info("Exception caught in init in CommentAction ..." + ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

```java
    public void updateCommentStatus(RowEditEvent event){
        try{
            CommentManager commentManager = new CommentManager();
            Comment comment = (Comment)event.getObject();
            logger.info("*****************************************************");  
            logger.info("comment Iddddddddddd: " +comment.getCommentId());
            logger.info("comment Statusssssss: " +comment.getCommentStatus());
            commentManager.updateCommentStatus(comment);
        } catch(Exception ex){
            logger.info("Exception caught in updateCommentStatus in CommentAction ..." + ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```